# Save list to manytomany field not using the ID field

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

Im trying to save a list to a manyToManyfield, but I need to use another field beside the ID of the object. I want it to match the list against the field called `extid`

Here is my models:

```
class Used_benefit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    extid = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="External ID")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Used_benefit, blank=True, null=True, related_name="benefits_used")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)    

    objects = UserManager()
```

Here is how I try to save the objects:

```
webuser = UserProfile.objects.get(username__exact=user_id)
productlist = soup.personrecord.productlist.string #The list looks like this: 1,2,6


if productlist:
    webuser.benefits.add(benefits__extid=productlist)


webuser.save()
```

But that method does not work. What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if productlist:
    productlist = productlist.split(",")
    webuser.benefits.add(*Used_benefit.objects.filter(extid__in=productlist))
```

You don't need `webuser.save()` unless you're making other changes to webuser object.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Shouldn't I split the list after `if productlist` ? Not sure what would happen if the productlist was empty or missing?

Comment: Yes, you're right, split it after `if productlist`. If you split empty string you will get `['']`. Also note i added `*` to expand `add` arguments

Comment: Very nice! Thank you again.